# C# class design, flexible payment rules

Tags: c#, single-responsibility-principle

I'm currently modeling a system responsible for managing royalty payments. A royalty may be as simple as:

- Pay Author A 15% of revenue

or as complex as either:

- Pay Author B 15% of revenue up to 1000 quantity sold, then 12% of revenue
- Also pay Author B $1.50 per each sold up to 1000 quantity sold

or:

- Pay Author C 15% of revenue for the first $1,000 revenue, then 12% of revenue

In short, a payment may either be a flat amount per each sold or a percentage of revenue. The condition for payment may be based on quantity sold or on revenue. I've tried to design a class (which corresponds closely to the database table behind the scenes) that encompasses all this flexibility by specifying types for the payment range and payment values. However, I'm worried I may be trying to have this class do too much and may be backing myself into a corner should we need to accommodate additional scenarios in the future. I'm seeking suggestions for alternative design approaches.

```
public class PaymentRule
{
    // I'm not 100% comfortable with this, as this will
    // really be an Int32 value for quantity sold ranges
    public decimal RangeMinimum { get; set; }
    public decimal? RangeMaximum { get; set; }

    // This will always be a decimal value, but may represent
    // a dollar amount or percentage depending on the context
    public decimal PaymentValue { get; set; }

    // Specify a type for the range: QuantitySold or Revenue
    public string RangeType { get; set; }

    // Specify a type for the value: AmountPerEachSold or RevenuePercentage
    public decimal ValueType { get; set; }

    public decimal CalculateRoyaltyDue(int quantitySold, decimal revenue)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**UPDATE 5/9/2012:**

I should mention that these rules must be persisted to a SQL Server database.

Comment: You might need a rules engine.

Comment: You're writing the system, but some non-programmers will _use_ it. How does he associate payment rules to authors? He needds to be able to extend the system himself? The UI consists of a simple drop down, or can the user be burdened with a DSL? Or a simple list of payment rules? Will there be edge cases where a specific implementation seems appropriate?

Comment: @StefanHanke The current UI is fairly tightly bound to the assumption that every payment rule will have a range minimum (even if the minimum is 0) and an optional range maximum. A range type must be selected from a dropdown  (revenue or quantity sold). A payment value must be specified, and the payment value type must be selected from a dropdown (revenue percentage or amount per each sold). I've updated the original question to indicate the optional nature of the RangeMaximum property.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [specification pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern) - this can of complex rule specification is exactly what it is designed to help with.

> In computer programming, the specification pattern is a particular software design pattern, whereby business rules can be recombined by chaining the business rules together using boolean logic.
>
> A specification pattern outlines a business rule that is combinable with other business rules. In this pattern, a unit of business logic inherits its functionality from the abstract aggregate Composite Specification class. The Composite Specification class has one function called IsSatisfiedBy that returns a boolean value. After instantiation, the specification is "chained" with other specifications, making new specifications easily maintainable, yet highly customizable business logic. Furthermore upon instantiation the business logic may, through method invocation or inversion of control, have its state altered in order to become a delegate of other classes such as a persistence repository.

Comment: It seems like LINQ handles everything this pattern accomplishes. Or am I missing the point?

Answer (score -1):

I would try to build some sort of fluent interface combining extension methods, linq expressions, method chining and named arguments, maybe something like this:

```
var revenue = 12000;
var ruleA = Rules.PayAuthor(15).PercentOf(revenue)
var ruleB = Rules.PayAuthor(15).PercentOf(revenue).UpTo(soldUnits:1000).Then(12).PercentOf(revenue)

var royalltyA = Royallty.For(ruleA, whenSoldUnitsIs: 1500);
var royalltyB = Royallty.For(ruleB, whenSoldUnitsIs: 1500);
```

Comment: Likely payment rules will be persisted some where and this fluent interface could never be used.

Comment: I've added persistence requirements, as I feel it has a significant impact on the proposed solution.

Comment: You right, I never took in mind persistence aspects. Nevertheless you can still build a fluent interface, set properties on an underlying model, calculate the revenue, and then save the object. You will need a few tweeks, but still possible. And yes, the proposed solution won't work at all.